# Why does hiding a containing div mean the child wont show in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sammy.js

The following code works but i would like to replace the lines $("#homepage").hide(); with $("#page").hide(); so i can take care of multiple pages. the problem is that the page will hide the page div but not show the homepage div again but it will show and hide the divs correctly if there are no parent divs involved.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="homepage">
        <h1>home</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="advert">
        <h1>advert</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var app = $.sammy(function() {
        this.get('#/', function() {
          $("#ad").hide();
          $("#homepage").show();
        });
        this.get('#ad/', function() {
          $("#homepage").hide();
          $("#ad").show();
        });
      });
      app.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i modify the code as follows to demonstrate my intended usage:

```
      var app = $.sammy(function() {
        this.get('#/', function() {
          $("#page").hide();
          $("#homepage").show();
        });
        this.get('#ad/', function() {
          $("#page").hide();
          $("#ad").show();
        });
      });
      app.run();
```

this code produces a window that is blank and does not show the homepage or ad page. i have tried with multiple different routing libraries.

Comment: when the parent is hidden it follows that all its child is also hidden

Comment: but setting show after it is hidden should make it visible

Comment: `$("#homepage")` selector does nothing (at least from your code sample) because you don't have any elements with this id

Comment: this was an error with my example now fixed

Comment: As @guradio pointed out, you are trying to reveal child elements within a hidden parent. When you call `$("#parent").hide()` and `$("#child").show()`, it will set `#child` `display` property to `block`, however the parent element will still have `display: none`, there is no way to make it visible.

Comment: You should have it outside the hidden parent... But if you really can't, you could try to [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the children and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it to the `<body>`...

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the parent , also the child will be hide coz their are connected to each other. as you can see the hierarchy design of the tag. So if you want to show the

```
<div id="homepage"></div>
```

and hide the

```
<div id="page"></div>
```

you should take the #homepage outside the scope of #page. That's the proper rule.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: thats the proper rule, does help. but what about when the scope is the body?

Comment: If scope is body? In the first place you should not hide the body tag. you should create another container inside the body for you to able to control on things inside the body. so you should not hide the body tag.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't used sammy.js library. I found simple sample example. check below link.
`https://jsfiddle.net/KZknm/34/`

```
$.sammy(function(){
        // bind to #:page where :page can be some value
        // we're expecting and can be retrieved with this.params
        this.get('#:page',function(){
            // Demo just finds the div within #pages and loads it
            // within the #container
            $('#container').empty().append(
                $('#pages #'+this.params['page']+'_html').clone()
            );
        });
    }).run();
```

here is Html

```
<!-- very simple container that may be changed with clicks -->
<div id="container">
    <h1>Default Page</h1>
    <p>This is the default page</p>
</div>

<!-- Dummy navigation list using hash links -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#foo">Load "foo.html"</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bar">Load "bar.html"</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- fake ajax content--for the purposes of this demo, we just load
     content from another source (in this case named divs) -->
<div id="pages" style="display:none">
    <div id="foo_html">
        <h1>Foo page</h1>
        <p>This is the foo page.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bar_html">
        <h1>Bar page</h1>
        <p>This is the bar page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21396988)

Comment: totally agree :)